# Get domain name as meta title via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to get the domain name of page as meta title via javascript in html?
Can somebody please paste the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `appendChild` to add elements to your `head`.

I have no idea how well this will fare with search bots.

This site is not for asking others to program for you, but I guess it's hard to get started if you don't know where to start, and it didn't take any time for me to answer.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

</body>

<script>
  const createTitleTag = (title) => {
    let headEl = document.querySelector('head');
    let titleEl = document.createElement('title');
    titleEl.innerText = title;

    headEl.appendChild(titleEl);
  }

  createTitleTag(location.host);
</script>

</html>
```